# "Hint request" on how to solve linear algebra exercise (ex2,ch3,Peter Lax,2ed).

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this exercise (exercise 2, chapter 3 from the "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" Second Edition by Peter Lax). It says:

Let

$$\sum_{j=1}^n{t_{ij}x_j} = u_i; (i=1,2,...,m)$$

be an overdetermined system of linear equations - that is, the number $m$ of equations is greater than the number $n$ of unknowns $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$. Take the case in spite of the overdeterminancy, this system of equations has a solution, and assume that this solution is unique. Show that it's possible to select a subset of $n$ of these equations which uniquely determine the solution. $\blacksquare$

(Sorry about the black square. It's the way I figured out to mark the end of the problem statement.)

I can't figure out how to solve this exactly. What I have tried to do is to work with a linear transformation $T: K^n \rightarrow K^m$, where $K$ is a field (subfield of the complex numbers; it is the book's convention that a field, if not further specified, is a subfield of the complex numbers), such that $$T(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = (\sum_{j=1}^n{t_{1j}x_j}, \sum_{j=1}^n{t_{2j}x_j}, ..., \sum_{j=1}^n{t_{mj}x_j})$$

Then the problem set tells me that there is a $u \in K^m$ such that there is a unique $x \in K^n$ with $Tx = u$. I can then show that $N_T$ is trivial because if it wasn't, and there was some $y \neq 0$ in $N_T$, then $T(x + y) = Tx = u$, which is an absurd because $x + y \neq x$ and by hypothesis I have that $x$ is the only element in $K^n$ such that $Tx = u$.

Now with the nullspace/range theorem, I know that the dimension of the range of $T$ is $n$ because $dim(N_T) = 0$.

There is where I stop.

Intuitively, it seems that because $dim(R_T) = n$, there are $m-n$ components of $u$ which are "linear combinations" of its other $n$ components. If I can show this, then I'm done, because that would mean that there are $m-n$ equations which are linear combinations of the other $n$ equations, and thus can be removed from the system without affecting it in any way.

Any hints on how to go about solving this problem?

**Edit**

I've replaced occurrences of "image" with "range", also replaced "kernel" with "nullspace". $R_T$ means the range of T, and $N_T$ means the nullspace of T. Previously I was writing $Im(T)$ for the image of $T$ (i.e. the range of $T$), and $Ker(T)$ for the kernel of $T$ (i.e. the nullspace of $T$). Now I've fixed the notation. In some of my comments you'll still see the "old notation" though.

Comment: Hint: You want to show that there are $n$ linearly independent row vectors in $T$. Suppose there are $r<n$. (It could not be $>n$. Why?) Derive contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by "in $T$"? Does it mean in the image (i.e. range) of $T$? I'm asking because $T$ itself isn't a set of row vectors (that I know). The domain of $T$ is, the nullspace (kernel) of $T$ is, the image (range) of $T$ is. Are you referring to one of those? If you mean the image of $T$, then the $dim(Im(T)) = n$ already shows I can select $n$ linearly independent row vectors in $Im(T)$. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I think I should clarify. Whenever I say "image", I mean "range", and whenever I say "kernel", I mean "nullspace". So, $Ker(T)$ is the nullspace of T, and $Im(T)$ is the range of T. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Sorry I guess I misunderstood your notation. I meant the matrix $T=(t_{ij})$. The row vectors are $(t_{11}, t_{12},...t_{1n}), (t_{21}, t_{22},...,t_{2n}), ...$. Because the question is asking you to pick $n$ vectors (or $n$ rows), I don't think the dimension argument helps much.